# Is it an ODR violation to have inconsistent noexcept in declaration?

Tags: c++, c, language-lawyer, noexcept, one-definition-rule

This is a two part question, the first regarding something written entirely in C++, the second part regarding the interaction between functions written in C but called from C++.

### Part 1

Is it an ODR or other violation to have different translation units see different `noexcept` specifiers on the declaration for the same function? Specifically, if one unit sees:

```
void foo();
```

while another one sees:

```
void foo() noexcept;
```

Is it an ODR or other violation? You may assume that the function in reality never throws (i.e., it actually could be declared `noexcept`).

### Part 2

Is it a violation if all C++ code sees the declaration as `extern "C" void foo() noexcept;`, but the function is actually defined (implemented) in C where the declaration (obviously) does not include the `noexcept`?

Comment: If it's defined in C, shouldn't you use `extern "C"` to declare it in C++?

Comment: It's an ODR violation unless _"...each definition consists of the same sequence of tokens..."_ see: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition

Comment: "nction is actually defined (implemented) in C" -- C++ does not, as far as I know, define the semantics of C code that is linked to C++.  As far as I know, all C code linked to C++ is unspecified how it works.  Of course, in practice, it works.

Comment: @Barmar - I do: see the first sentence in part 2.

Answer (score 7):

> Is it an ODR ... violation?

It is not an ODR violation. These:

> ```
> void foo();
> void foo() noexcept;
> ```

are only declarations. They are not definitions and One Definition Rule does not restrict them.

> is it an ... other violation?

Yes. It violates following rule (quote from latest satandard draft):

> [except.spec]
>
> If a declaration of a function does not have a noexcept-specifier, the declaration has a potentially throwing exception specification unless *[exception that does not apply]*, in which cases the exception specification is as specified below and **no other declaration for that function shall have a noexcept-specifier**. ... A diagnostic is required only if the exception specifications are not the same within a single translation unit.

---

> Is it a violation if all C++ code sees the declaration as extern "C" void foo() noexcept;, but the function is actually defined (implemented) in C where the declaration (obviously) does not include the noexcept?

Technically maybe. But C++ standard doesn't really apply to C, so this is probably under-specified. Even if the program is technically ill-formed, I'm not sure if there's any practical problem if one TU thinks that a function is `noexcept` as long as that function never throws.

For what it's worth, glibc declares standard C functions with `throw()` when using GCC only when included into C++.

Comment: The declarations without `noexcept` are in C, not C++. Does that rule still apply?

Comment: @Barmar Maybe; I don't know. Interaction between C and C++ is a gray area.

Comment: That's only an issue for part 2 of the question, so this answer is fine for part 1.